# How to use Frictionless sharing to post to the users wall with open graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sharing

So I've heard we can now post to the users wall without them prompting it, and without them confirming the text that is posted.  First of all is that correct?  I don't want to do anything that risks my app being blocked for breaking policy!  I can't find much on this new subject.  If that is correct do I have to do anything special to enable it or do I literally just start posting to their wall?  Obviously I have requested the wall post permission.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find the documentation of Frictionless Requests

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: I replied to this, where did it go?!  Thanks for the link.  This seems to be talking about when you invite someone to the app, is that right?  What my client is asking for is if we can say automatically "x just did x on this app" without them prompting or confirming it.  Does frictionless sharing now allow this?  The facebook policy still says the user has to initiate all posts to their wall but I thought that was the opposite of frictionless sharing?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked for the same thing and this is what I found. You need to define `objects` and `actions` in order to use frictionless sharing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#define